# JSSOR Reload carousel with different options

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am developing a responsive website which I would like to change the number of slides showing at different levels and wondered whether there was a way to quickly reload the slider with different options when the window is resized?  I am currently having to refresh the page to force the slider to reload.

Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

When you resize window, 'resize' events fires frequently. It's high performance sonsuming operation to reload slider in the period of resizing.

It's highly recommended that not to reload while resizing.